# Getting a routing error from certain pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have this route

`profile GET    /contacts/:id(.:format)  {:controller=>"my_devise/contacts", :action=>"profile"}`

This is my controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :get_current_user

    def get_current_user
        @current_user = current_user
    end

end
```

If i have this link in my view/layouts/application.html.erb file `<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path(@current_user)  %>` on the url `http://localhost:3000/contacts/1`, i have no errors, but if i try to hit the url `http://localhost:3000/contacts`, I get the error below

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:controller=>"my_devise/contacts", :action=>"profile"}
```

If i remove the link in my application.html.erb file and hit `http://localhost:3000/contacts`, the error goes away.

Why would that link cause this error?

**EDIT**

Full routes file

```
$ rake routes
          users_sign_out GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)      {:controller=>"devise/sessions", :action=>"destroy"}
           users_sign_in GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:controller=>"my_devise/sessions", :action=>"new"}
                    home GET    /home(.:format)                {:action=>"index", :controller=>"my_devise/sessions"}
                contacts GET    /contacts(.:format)            {:action=>"list", :controller=>"my_devise/contacts"}
                 profile GET    /contacts/:id(.:format)        {:controller=>"my_devise/contacts", :action=>"profile"}
            edit_profile GET    /contacts/:id/edit(.:format)   {:controller=>"my_devise/contacts", :action=>"edit"}
                         POST   /contacts/:id/edit(.:format)   {:controller=>"my_devise/contacts", :action=>"update_user"}
                    more GET    /more/:id(.:format)            {:controller=>"my_devise/contacts", :action=>"more"}
                         POST   /home(.:format)                {:action=>"create_new_user", :controller=>"my_devise/sessions"}
           users_sign_up GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       {:controller=>"my_devise/registrations", :action=>"new"}
                         POST   /users/sign_up(.:format)       {:controller=>"my_devise/registrations", :action=>"new"}
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/sessions"}
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"devise/registrations"}
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"my_devise/sessions"}
                         POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       {:action=>"create", :controller=>"my_devise/sessions"}
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"my_devise/sessions"}
                         POST   /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"create", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  {:action=>"new", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      {:action=>"update", :controller=>"devise/passwords"}
                         GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        {:action=>"cancel", :controller=>"my_devise/registrations"}
                         POST   /users(.:format)               {:action=>"create", :controller=>"my_devise/registrations"}
                         GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       {:action=>"new", :controller=>"my_devise/registrations"}
                         GET    /users/edit(.:format)          {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"my_devise/registrations"}
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               {:action=>"update", :controller=>"my_devise/registrations"}
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"my_devise/registrations"}
              home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)          {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
                    root        /                              {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
                    root        /                              {:controller=>"home", :action=>"index"}
```

Comment: This doesn't address your actual question, but you don't (shouldn't, anyway) need the before filter or get_current_user method. Just replace `@current_user` with `current_user` in your view (the same as you call it in your `get_current_user` method).

Comment: can u show the routes.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your actual question, it's because you don't have a route for that (`/contacts` - note no id). Your route is `/contacts/:id(.:format)` - the format is optional, but the id is not. You'll need to make the id optional, too, or create another route.

Comment: Question updated with full routes file. I do have a /contacts route

Comment: Is there a `profile` method in your `my_devise/contacts` controller?

Comment: Yes there is. It works just fine if i remove `<%= link_to "Profile", profile_path(@current_user) %>` from my application.html.erb file.

Comment: Or does it have a custom `to_params` method?

Comment: You're right. Current_user was blank because i went to the sign in page and signed in and now it works. Not sure why my authentication filter is not working right now, but that's another question for another day.

Answer (score 0):

The routes is like this

contacts GET    /contacts(.:format)            {:action=>"list", :controller=>"my_devise/contacts"}

Here we have to give the format also. If we give contacts it will throw routing error. So please enter the format also.

Comment: Rails 3 provides the :constraints option that can be specified on a route. This worked to route the same url to different controllers, depending on the format.

Comment: resources :party_favors, :module => "web", :constraints => {:format => :html}